# How to read and write XML File without certain nodes in Java

Tags: java, xml, parsing, dom, xpath

I am trying to read an XML File and write a new XML file without the first node(root element) and the second node.
Here an example..

I got this: afile.xml

```
<soap:Envelope>
 <soap:Body>
  <note>
      <to>Tove</to>
      <from>Jani</from>
      <heading>Reminder</heading>
      <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
  </note>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

and want this : bfile.xml

```
<note>
  <to>Tove</to>
  <from>Jani</from>
  <heading>Reminder</heading>
  <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

Comment: You could use XPath to extract the <note> and write it to bfile.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use XSLT, for instance XSLT 2.0 can do it with a simple stylesheet

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="2.0">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:copy-of select="//note" copy-namespaces="no"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You need to use an XSLT 2.0 processor like Saxon 9 to run the code given above.

If you don't know the name of the element you want to copy then using `<xsl:copy-of select="/*/*/*" copy-namespaces="no"/>` instead of `<xsl:copy-of select="//note" copy-namespaces="no"/>` should do.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following ...

```
import java.util.Map;

import cjm.component.cb.map.ToMap;
import cjm.component.cb.xml.ToXML;

public class NoteExtract
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    try
    {
        String xml = "<soap:Envelope><soap:Body><note><to>Tove</to><from>Jani</from><heading>Reminder</heading><body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body></note></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>";

        Map<String, Object> map = new ToMap().convertToMap(xml);

        Map<String, Object> mapEnvelope = (Map<String, Object>) map.get("soap:Envelope");

        Map<String, Object> mapBody = (Map<String, Object>) mapEnvelope.get("soap:Body");

        String extractedXML = (new ToXML().convertToXML(mapBody, true)).toString();

        System.out.println("Extracted XML: " + extractedXML);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Output:

```
 -------- XML Detected -------- 
 -------- Map created Successfully -------- 
 -------- Map Detected -------- 
 -------- XML created Successfully -------- 
Extracted XML: <note><to>Tove</to><body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body><from>Jani</from><heading>Reminder</heading></note>
```

Get the [Conversion Box](http://capsulesforthejavamind.blogspot.in/2015/01/conversion-box.html) JAR for this ...